# Access to Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I need help. It turns out I installed drupal 7 Acquia . During the installation process introduced as a different user name to admin, admin without knowing it was so important. The fact is that I now logged out of my drupal and more can no longer access my site administration. And therefore I can not access the modules, content , login ...
Any suggestions ?

Thanks you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since password is definitely encrypted this is what I would do:

1. Find out where user data is stored...some user table. Use PhpMyAdmin or similar tool.
2. Start new Drupal installation somewhere else and this time enter and remember username/password you need.
3. Access new database and collect encrypted password.
4. Replace old encrypted password with new value.